# Having Issue on Selecting Option From Hidden Box in FireFox With jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at **[This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pkv3q4z9/1/)** in **Firefox** browser(it is working fine in Chrome) and let me know why the Select option is not click-able in firefox?

the process is like after selecting `international` radio the `#the-box` hidden button which contains a select option will dropdown. It is how ever none select-able in firefox!

```
$('input:radio[name=map]').on('change', function () {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=map]:checked').val();
    switch (val) {
        case 'local':
             $('#the-box').hide().removeClass('hidden').slideUp();
            break;
        case 'international':
            $('#the-box').hide().removeClass('hidden').slideDown();
            break;

    }
});
```

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using? seems clickable for me.

Comment: I am using 42.0, can you select from the Select Option? what version you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You html is wrong because HTML5 doesn't allow interactive elements (such as select) within buttons., you cannot add a select inside a button. fixed it for you here:

[Here is the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rhxd6pmr/1/)

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="map" value="local" />Local
<br />
<input type="radio" name="map" value="international" />International
<br />
<div class="radio-div list-group" style="margin-bottom:0px;">
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item"><strong> Minimize Overlap Between Projects And:</strong>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="list-group-item hidden" id="the-box"></button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper hidden">
<select class="selectpicker">
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('select').selectpicker();
$('input:radio[name=map]').on('change', function () {
    var val = $('input:radio[name=map]:checked').val();
    switch (val) {
        case 'local':
             $('#the-box').hide().removeClass('hidden').slideUp();
            break;
        case 'international':
            $('.wrapper').hide().removeClass('hidden').slideDown();
            break;

    }
});
```

Note that your `<option>` must contain a value otherwise it will save nothing so proper option: `<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>`